# Formatting BigInteger leads empty for 0

Tags: c#

I am formatting a BigInteger value of 0 and get an empty string as a result. Is that the expected behavior?

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger value = 0;
string xx = value.ToString("#", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

xx is string.Empty after these two statements. If I set value to 10 I'm getting "10".

Comment: Plus one. It's obviously by design but surely it's about as useful as a trap door in a canoe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's the expected behavior. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#SpecifierD):

> If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the "`#`" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string. **Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position** in the result string.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

You can use `0` as a format string instead if you always want at least one digit:

```
string xx = value.ToString("0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Yields:

- `0` → `"0"`
- `10` → `"10"`

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for the "#" custom specifier:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD

> Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, **even if zero is the only digit in the string**. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed.

In your case 0 is not a significant digit and is therefore not displayed.

Use `0` as the specifier instead.